# How to display the record data as a link in a ext js grid

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a extjs grid. For the column "TransactionType" I want the transaction type to be displayed as a link.
On click of the link, a new window should open. With the below code I get the link and when I click on it, a new window opens. But the original page gives a 404 error

```
function renderData(records){
   var r = records[i].data;  //records is the data grid
   r.TransactionType_link='<a  href="" onclick="openTransactionDetails('+r.tranid+');">'+r.TransactionType+'</a>';
 }
function openTransactionDetails(tranid){
var url = "/MyProject/pages/TransactionDetails.jsp?tranid="+tranid;
window.open(url,"TransactionDetails", "height=600,width=1080,left=250,top=300,resizable=No,scrollbars=Yes,status=No,addressbar=no");
}
```

After clicking on the link I get the error 
'The requested resource (/MyProject/pages/) is not available.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return false in the `onclick`, so that the page doesn't try to navigate anywhere:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openTransactionDetails('+r.tranid+'); return false">'+r.TransactionType+'</a>'
```